# Equation in implicit form

Tags: equation-solving

This is simple example:

```
 v = {1.48622576, 1.53444276, 1.42299438}
 v/(v + 1)
 Out[1]:= {0.597784, 0.605436, 0.587288}
```

In the above case expression v/(v + 1) is in explicit form.
I would like to find k for v = {1.48622576, 1.53444276, 1.42299438}
wherein

```
 Log(0.5(1-k))/Log(0.5(1+k))=v (expression in implicit form)
```

Comment: You have to look up how to properly set-up equations and correct your mistakes /syntax/.

Comment: `k /. 
 Table[FindRoot[
   Log[0.5 (1 - k)]/Log[0.5 (1 + k)] == v, {k, 1/2}], {v, {1.48622576,
     1.53444276, 1.42299438}}]

Out[103]= {0.136539357217, 0.14739964925, 0.121702474657}`

Answer (score 2):

As [Daniel Lichtblau](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/51/daniel-lichtblau) said in [his comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46156/equation-in-implicit-form#comment136966_46156) the following works:

```
vs = {1.48622576, 1.53444276, 1.42299438};
eq[k_] := Log[0.5 (1 - k)]/Log[0.5 (1 + k)]
ks = k /. Table[FindRoot[eq[k] == v, {k, 1/2}], {v, vs}]
```

> ```
> {0.136539, 0.1474, 0.121702}
> ```

Then you can check if the answer is correct:

```
vs == eq /@ ks
```

> ```
> True
> ```